# Count rows using criteria and projection

Tags: hibernate, count, criteria

I'm trying to get number of rows for specified criteria using projection. The idea is to count all items whose owner from specified city.

Entities structure looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Expose
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
}

class Item extends BaseEntity{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = 'owner_id')
    Owner owner;
}

class Owner extends BaseExntity{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    City city;
}

class City extends BaseExntity{
    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;
}
```

To select data I use next code with hibernate criteria:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Item.class);

//just select all instances that have cityId = 1
c.createAlias("owner.city", "city");
c.add(Restrictions.like("city.id", 1L));
c.list(); //1st invocation, this works well

//Trying to count instances that have cityId = 1
ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.rowCount(), "count");

c.setProjection(properties);
c.list(); //2nd invocation, here I receive an exception - object not found: CITY1_.ID
```

At second c.list() invocation sql query looks like:
*Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from item this_ where city1_.id like ?*

And it's not clear for me why first c.list() invocation works well but when i'm trying to count rows with projection it doesn't work and throws *object not found: CITY1_.ID*

Hibernate version is 4.3.4.Final

Comment: What happens if you call `c.list();` only once?

Comment: If I remove first invocation of c.list() it fails with the same error - object not found: CITY1_.ID

Comment: I think you have to add the alias to the projection using the `Projections.alias` method.

Comment: Didn't catch your idea, could you please provide an example?

Comment: can update with sql query when first call to `c.list();` is made?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**
Looks like hibernate doesn't support aliases with multiple associations for Projections, but for Criteria does. Thus I changed criteria alias from:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Item.class);
c.createAlias("owner.city", "city");
c.add(Restrictions.like("city.id", 1L));
```

to:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Item.class, "i");
c.createAlias("i.owner", "owner");
c.createAlias("owner.city", "city");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("city.id", 1L));
```

and now projection count works well.